# copying list of files with comments

Tags: bash

I have a build script that copies a few files to a build folder.

The build script is used for various applications, and each application need slightly different files deployed. Because of this, comments for the files, embedded in the script, are needed.

My first attempt looks like this

```
dest=$outputfolder
"rm *.* $dest
SRC_DIR="./../../source"

files=(
$SRC_DIR/../*.txt                                
$SRC_DIR/../resources/*.ico                      
$OUTPUTDIR/$OUTPUTFILENAME                       
#
#DS Binaries
$OUTPUTDIR/dslCommon.dll                         
$OUTPUTDIR/dslIPC.dll                            
$OUTPUTDIR/atVCLCommon.dll                       
$OUTPUTDIR/atSSI.dll                             

#BPL's
$BDSCOMMONDIR/BPL/dslVCLComponents.bpl          
$BDSCOMMONDIR/BPL/atVCLDataModules.bpl
)

for file in $files
 do
   echo $file
 done
```

Some of the variables above are arguments passed to the script.

Whats the best way to remove irrelevant lines in the file list above, and make it suitable for the for loop?

When searching, I only find examples with 'perfect' lists, i.e. no inline comments, empty lines etc.

Update: Answer below shows that the list can contain comments and empty lines, so no 'cleaning' is needed.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but as-is, the phrasing took me twice to realize you simply wanted to remove the blank lines and comments in files=(). Also, this question may (for better or worse) be suffering from a lack of "show us what you've tried".

Comment: Thanks Anaksunaman. Without a comment on a down vote, how is one to know?? To improve a question, constructive feedback is needed. A downvote without a comment should be a violation in my opinion, cause it does not do anything good for anybody.

Comment: You're welcome. I have mixed feelings overall, but it's certainly true that no clear feedback often means no improvement.

Comment: While I didn't downvote - downvotes are anonymous by design. Kinda cause people react badly to them. Also - eh, I don't think that accusing folks of not niceness, and linking the blog was the intention folks had with it.  Anyway - feedback... what do you mean by clean here? I'm having trouble parsing what you're trying to do as well, so opening with a bit more of an explanation of your goal, and where its falling short would be nice.

Comment: If the script works, might be better feedback on code review. Also, I've found that asking for "the best" way garners DV and VTC just by the nature of being personal opinion, and not an objective, qualified answer. (With the occasional exception, of course).

Comment: Thanks Journeman. With your comments, a downvote would be fine, in my opionin. Then I could clarify what I mean y 'clean' (remove irrelevant lines from the list) . With no comments, how to know? We are not mind readers.. We are just here to help each other, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you mean by '"clean" the files list above', but the first thing you should do is to use the `files` *array* you create, not some plain `files` variable:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"
 do something
 done
```

Additionally your code is prone to errors due to variables not being quoted. This is how creating an array works:

```
files=(
# comments are just comments
a
a b c    # three separate entries
"a b c"  # one entry
# therefore
/my directory/    # two entries
"/my directory/"  # one entry

# empty line doesn't matter
""
# the above is an empty entry

# this won't fail with paths containing spaces etc.
"$SRC_DIR/../"*.txt
"$OUTPUTDIR/$OUTPUTFILENAME"
"$OUTPUTDIR/dslCommon.dll"
"$BDSCOMMONDIR/BPL/dslVCLComponents.bpl"
)
```

Comment: Awesome! You addressed the two things I did not get, or was unsure about, how to create the array, and how to use it in the loop. To be clear, I thought I would need to 'clean' the list by sending it through 'tr' or some other command line utility before I could use it.